# Enthought Canopy User Input

Tags: python-2.7, input, enthought, canopy

I'm using Enthought Canopy on Mac OSX Lion.  I'm using this because of the ease at which modules and libraries can be downloaded and installed (had a lot of trouble downloading pandas and numpy through terminal due to a number of issues).
   So, now I'm doing my coding for a project in Canopy, which is OK (still prefer Wing, though).  The problem I have encountered is that I need to ask the user for input.  When I do, for instance:

```
 x = input('Enter your input here: ')
```

I get an EOF error as follows: `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

I was looking around and believe that this may be something which Canopy does not support.  Was wondering if this is, indeed, the case and if there is a solution/workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are entering this code in the IPython shell that is embedded in the Canopy editor. This is an upstream bug/deficiency in IPython's Qt console. Because the remote shell is not actually hooked up to a terminal, functions like `input()` and `raw_input()` need to be replaced to get the input from the GUI console widget instead. IPython (and thus Canopy) does replace `raw_input()` but does not replace `input()`. This code will work using Canopy's Python interpreter if you were to put it into a script and execute it from the command line, and it would also work in a terminal instance of IPython. It was most likely overlooked because it is usually considered a bad idea to use `input()`.

Please use `raw_input()` instead and parse the string that you get. You can use `eval()` if you must, but I do recommend using a more specific parsing/conversion function.